# Python3.X numpy.argsort()

Tags: python

I'm learning the numpy.

Now I have met a question about numpy.argsort().

This function return an array of indices of the same shape as 'a' that index data along the given axis in sorted order.

I have created an 3-D array,for the row of 68,87,56. I think it will return 1,2,0,but it return 2,0,1 actually.So I'm very confuse about this. Can someone hlep me ?

[image: code review]

Comment: `[68, 87, 56]` is NOT a 3-D array ! :O A list of size `n` is not a n-D array !

Answer (score 0):

The return value of 2,0,1 means that [ originalArray[2], originalArray[0], originalArray[1] ] puts the array in sorted order.